# How to replace a shapefile loaded in a hdf file?

Tags: python, r, hdf, rhdf5

How can I replace a shapefile loaded in a hdf file?
Basically, it is a bunch of shapefiles stacked in a hdf file...
I am able to access the hdf file stored location but it is rather in tables and unable to change it...
Is there a editor available ? I have checked with a viewer only which looks as in the image

preview of shapefile in hdf5][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J19fG.png

Comment: You don't say what your .h5 files are a product of but [this might help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442477/overlay-raster-h5-files-with-shape-files-to-get-night-light-data-in-r)

Comment: Its not a raster file.. Its a hdf5 file I have put a snapshot .

Comment: have your tried something like `<- terra::vect('river_edge_lines') ?, likely not correct as you don't provide full path and .h5 file name.

Comment: its not araster file. its a hdf file output from hecras.. under which it has geometry layer and several components following that as path

Comment: and you've reviewed [HEC_RAS and R](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/rasdocs/rassed1d/1d-sediment-transport-user-s-manual/viewing-results/visualizing-hdf5-results-with-r-python-and-matlab)? I don't have HEC-RAS installed and am on Linux.

Comment: you dont need hecras  . example  files are here with hdf extension 
 **g01.hdf **https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/download.aspx
... that library mentioned is only for viewing hdf5.

Comment: As viewed by `BiocManager::install("rhdf5")``rhdf5::h5ls('BaldEagleDamBrk.g01.hdf')` we see that the Polygon Info, Parts, and Points are matrix like objects, not shp files, The enclosed shapefiles retain their traditional construction/file structure...What are you trying to replace?

Comment: [hdf5r.Extra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdf5r.Extra/index.html) package has a `h5Write()` set of functions, might be worth to check.

Comment: Yes @Chris I would like to convert new shapefiles into tables (data ) and replace the old ones ...